# PHPExcel Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted after convert xlsx format

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

I wrote a method to read the excel files using PHPExcel library in Codeigniter. It is work fine for xls format. So I convert this file to xlsx format and test it. I is give following error when i check xlsx file.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 93 bytes) in /home/dinuka/workspace/sec_new/application/third_party/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php on line 1142
```

My excel file has 13 sheets. Issue is why it isn't work after convert same file. Why memory limit is not exhausted when use xls format?

Answer (score 0):

The memory requirements for the different Readers and Writers in PHPExcel aren't the same, even though the data storage inside the PHPEXcel object may be.

If you're working with larger files, then I'd recommend using cell caching to reduce the memory storage requirements for the PHPExcel object, allowing more of your php memory to be used by the Readers/Writers, and/or increasing your php memory limit.